# by the plate/plateful

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Are the following sentences correct? If so, what's the difference between a and b, and between c and d?

> a. They served spaghetti by the plateful.

> b. They served spaghetti by the plate.

> c. Tourists arrived by the busload.

> d. Tourists arrived by the bus.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions "plateful" and "busload" seem to indicate large amounts and large numbers. The expressions are specifying quantities of what was served or arrived, rather than the mode of delivery.

Sentence b, "They served spaghetti by the plate." doesn't seem very likely. If you refer to the mode of serving, "on a plate" would be more likely.

Sentence d, "Tourists arrived by the bus." could refer to how the tourists got there, and the article "the" would mean that the reference was to a known or mentioned bus, otherwise it would be "by bus".

Answer (score 1):

a. They served spaghetti by the plateful.
b. They served spaghetti by the plate.

These both mean nearly the same; 'by the plateful' implies large portions.

c. Tourists arrived by the busload.
d. Tourists arrived by the bus.

These do not mean the same. If tourists arrived **by the busload**, they arrived in large numbers, and came in full buses, and more than one of these. If they arrived **by the bus**, that just means that some tourists, number unknown, came in one, or possibly more, buses.